# Moment Generating Function

Tags: probability

I am little unsure if I am doing the following question right:

> Suppose Y is a discrete random variable such that
>
> $P(Y=0)=\frac{1}{3}$;  $P(Y=1)=\frac{1}{6}$; $P(Y=2)=\frac{1}{6}$;
>   $P(Y=3)=\frac{1}{3}$;
>
> a) Write down the moment generating function of $Y$.
>
> b) Find the mean and variance of $Y$.
>
> c) Suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent random variables with
>   the same distribution as $Y$. Compute $P(X_1 + X_2 = 3)$.

My solutions so far:

a) Defintion of MGF $$M(t) = E[e^{tX}] = \sum_{x}e^{tx}p(x)$$
So

$$M_Y(s) = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6}e^{t} + \frac{1}{6}e^{2t} + \frac{1}{3}e^{3t}$$

b) Using the following defintions:
$$ M'(0) = E[X]$$

$$M''(0) = E[X^2]$$

So

$M'(t) = e^{3t} + \frac{1}{3}e^{2t} + \frac{1}{6}e^t \implies M'(0) = \frac{3}{2}$

$M''(t) = 3e^{3t} + \frac{2}{3}e^{2t} + \frac{1}{6}e^t \implies M''(0) = \frac{23}{6}$

$Var(X) = \frac{23}{6} - (\frac{3}{2})^2 = \frac{19}{12}$

I am not sure how to do part c though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z=X_1+X_2$. Since they are independent random variables with the same distribution as $Y$
\begin{align}
M_Z(t) &= E[e^{t(X_1+X_2)}] 
\\
&= E[e^{tX_1}] \:E[e^{tX_2}] 
\\
&=(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6}e^{t} + \frac{1}{6}e^{2t} + \frac{1}{3}e^{3t})^2
\\
&=\frac1{36}(4+4e^t+5e^{2t}+10e^{3t}+5e^{4t}+4e^{5t}+4e^{6t})
\end{align}
Thus $P(Z=3)$ is the coefficient of $e^{3t}$, i.e.
$$
P(Z=3)=\frac{5}{18}
$$

Comment: How did you determine to pmf to get 5/18? The MGF that you calculated doesn't seem to match any of the table in my book (binomial, Poisson, geometric and negative)

Comment: $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent and same distribution and so $M_{X_1+X_2}(t)$ is the square of $M_Y(t)$. $P(X_1+X_2=3)$ is the coefficient of $e^{3t}$ and so it is $5/18$. The calculated mgf doesn't match any of the table in your book (binomial, Poisson, geometric and negative) because $Y$ is not among these distributions. But you can simply get probability from coefficient of $e^{kt}$ which is the advantage of using mgf because it automatically includes all the cases of each random variable, e.g, $X_1=0, X_2=3$, $X_1=1, X_2=2$ and etc.

Comment: If you enumerate the combination of $X1$ and $X2$ separately like other post, it is easy to get error. But with mgf, all the probability distribution are obtained at same time and it will not be easy to get error.

Answer (score 1):

a) looks good.

I'm not checking your answers for b), but the methodology looks fine.

For c), suppose $X_1$, $X_2$ are independent, are distributed as $Y$ is, and $Z = X_1 + X_2$.

$Y$ takes on only the following values: $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$.

If $Z = 3$, what are the possible values that $X_1$ and $X_2$ can take?

Well, $X_1, X_2$ are both distributed as $Y$ is, so they take on the same values as $Y$ (note here I don't mean that they are equal to $Y$).

Remember, we're only looking at cases where $Z = 3$.

If $X_1 = 0$, $X_2$ must be $3$. I will represent this with the pair $(0, 3)$.
$(3, 0)$ is another way to get $Z = 3$.
We can also find $(1, 2), (2, 1)$ as possibilities.

So:
$$P((X_1, X_2) = (0, 3)) = P((X_2, X_1) = (3, 0) = P(X_1 = 0 \cap X_2 = 3) = P(X_1 = 0)P(X_2 = 3)$$
using independence and you can do something similar for $(1, 2)$ and $(2, 1)$.